# Css banner not showing up

Tags: html, css, image, banner

I have some CSS right here, and the banner I put isn't showing up. Any help?

```
css:

.home {
display: flex;
background: url('./images/banner.jpg') no-repeat center;
height: 100vh;
}

html:

<section class="home" id="home">
  <div class="max-width">
    <div class="home-content">
      <div class="text-1">Hello, my name is</div>
      <div class="text-2">Sefatul Bahar</div>
      <div class="text-3">And I'm an <span>accountant</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the dev-tools of your browser. Here are examples: [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools). These tools will help you discover computed CSS attributes. If you can't fix your problem this way, please include more code. Make sure to read ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Welcome to StackOverflow and happy debugging!

Comment: @Barthy I'm on a chromebook and dev tools don't work on this device. Thank you for asking to put more code, I will change that now.

Comment: Change the `height: 100vh;` to some `px` to find the problem like try `height: 100px;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might make more sense with the HTML too. You didn't provide your HTML so I'm not exactly sure what you're going for but this is as good as i can get with just a little bit of CSS.

```css
/*I used a different image just to see if this would work*/

.home {
    display: flex;
    background: url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/187161.jpg);
    /*you were missing the -repeat and -position*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Help</title>

</head>

<body>
    <main class="home">
        <div>
            <h1> Hello </h1>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>

</html>
```

```css
/*I used a different image just to see if this would work*/

.home {
    display: flex;
    background: url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/187161.jpg);
  /*you were missing the -repeat and -position*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```